# Best description

Tags: word-usage

I'm working on a business interruption plan and want to describe lack of efficiency should an event happen.  I wonder if I should say "lack of efficiency" or "poor efficiency" or are both grammatically equal?

Comment: Why do you think “lack of efficiency” might not be a good way to express your idea?

Comment: I don't.  I have that in the description, but thought about alternatives and wondered if grammatically there was a right or wrong.  I like "lack of" more than "poor".

Comment: Lack of efficiency implies absolutely no efficiency. Perhaps reduced efficiency reflects what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

*Lack of efficiency* is absolutely fine.

You could also use *low efficiency* as [a more popular alternative](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=low%20efficiency%2C%20poor%20efficiency&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clow%20efficiency%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpoor%20efficiency%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Clow%20efficiency%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpoor%20efficiency%3B%2Cc0) to *poor efficiency*.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly "inefficient" or "inefficiency". The two are pretty standard and feel more concise to me.